# Loop script inteiro -- mais de uma variável R

Tags: r

Possuo um script com cinco variáveis.

Suponhamos que as variáveis e seus tipos/classes de dados sejam os seguintes:

- var1(date)
- var2(date)
- var3(date)
- var4(date)
- var5(numeric)

Gostaria de importar uma planilha com cada coluna/ entrada correspondendo ao nome e tipo das variáveis em um dataframe. Assim sendo:

```
df <- xlsx("planilha.xlsx", sheet = "nome_plan")
```

Seria possível iterar o código inteiro para cada uma das linhas do dataframe?

Algo como:

```
for (i in df) {
    executar_script(i)
}
```

Comment: Fernando, tudo é possível, mas seria mais fácil sugerir se soubermos o que você tem e o que você quer. Descreva melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Segue o script inteiro: https://pastebin.com/dEt9EMhz. As cinco variáveis estão comentadas no início.

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas se a galera daqui vai querer ler e entender um script com 376 linhas que não foram eles que escreveram. Tente reduzir a tua pergunta para algo mais simples e que seja reproduzível. De preferência, dando uma descrição menos genérica do que a dada na pergunta original.

Comment: Reforçando o comentário anterior, ninguém vai parar para entender um sript de 300+ linhas só para responder uma pergunta sobre loop; escreva um script simples de teste e poste-o junto com um exemplo de dados. Mas o que pode fazer no seu caso é escrever seu script como uma função, salvando-a em um arquivo separado. Carregue com `source` e use as funções da família `apply` para aplicá-la à vários elementos de uma lista ou data.frame.

Comment: Carlos, farei isso. Obrigado